# Why Doesn't DataObject.SetText(String) accept empty string?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is partially a rant and partially genuine curiosity.  Does anyone know why [System.Windows.Forms.DataObject's SetText(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hytkyb6y.aspx) method does not accept an empty string as its argument?  It states that this will throw an ArgumentNullException (even though it is not actually null).

I could understand it not accepting a null value, but it seems very unusual that it would not allow an empty string.  Is there something I am missing here, or was this just some arbitrary decision by an API designer?

Comment: Possibly this is a wrapper around a COM function that will fail on empty strings.

Comment: My guess would be that this is because the counterpart of `SetText`, the `GetText` method, returns `String.Empty` to indicate that the data object does not contain data in the UnicodeText format. Essentially, `String.Empty` plays the role of `null` in this case, so you need to make `SetText` not accept `String.Empty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [source](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) [says](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html):

```
public virtual void SetText(string textData, TextDataFormat format)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textData))
    {
        //
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("textData");
    }
}
```

But that's not the answer to your question, as you ask *why* this is. Browsing through the source I couldn't find an answer, nor during a quick scan of MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the codinghorror link, btw - you've now set me off on a terrible (and wonderful) recursive path of reading more and more of Jeff's posts again.  :)